# How can I use net40 packages from NuGet when project's target framework is set to net45?

Tags: nuget

I have a web app with a few NuGet packages. The web project targets .net 4.5. Now, one package is behaving strange. I get to download it from the official repository, but it's just not added to my bin folder.

I guess the reason is that the package downloaded contains a .dll under **/net40/** folder. Adding it manually works, but NuGet is not picking it up. Is there a way I can setup this to work?

Comment: A .NET 4.5 project should use the net40 assembly if there is no net45 folder. NuGet will pick the highest compatible target framework. What NuGet package is it and what assembly is not being copied?

Comment: You're right. It turns out a colleague of mine had checked in a new version of an existing package to our private repository without increasing the version number. Worked for him, but failed for me, since packages are cached bot in the project and somewhere under app/localdata. After some cleanup, NuGet picks the net40 assembly with no problems.

TL;DR - Bad rerefernces in our project file.